# Unable to get friends despite permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making an application which needs to get friends of the current user

```
if ($user) {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$friends= $facebook->api('/me/friends');

}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {

    $params = array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos, user_friends');       

  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( $params);
}
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that the friends list returns empty for my current app. For an older app, albeit it works fine. The new app is public and I checked in the Status and Reciew area  where it says that the app has user_friends permission by default. I can't seem to understand what's wrong with this/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_login, user_friends now only gives access to friends using the *same app*, not all friends.